# Encrypting a string using AES 128 Bit encryption and a key

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

Imagine I have this key (base 64):

```
Jdn1jJsD5hFrip4jzHODyA==
```

If I want to encrypt a string using AES 128 bit and the above key, what facilities does the .NET framework provide for this case?

I've tried searching on MSDN, but haven't found anything useful I could use.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key appears to be encoded in Base64.

```
 byte[] binKey = System.Convert.FromBase64String(textKey);
```

will give you a 16 byte key. All encryption classes use `byte[]` keys.